# Display the result of doing 8 perfect shuffles of a deck of cards

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

### Explanation

A perfect shuffle is where a deck of cards is split exactly in half and the cards from each pile are alternately interleaved. The original bottom cards and the original top card must be preserved after a perfect shuffle.

After 8 perfect shuffles, a standard 52 card deck returns to its original order.

### Challenge

Write a program that displays the state of a deck of cards as it goes through 8 consecutive perfect shuffles. You may use any human-readable representation of a deck, provided that it displays the number and suit of each card in the deck in sequential order. It must display a representation of all of the cards, for all nine states.

This is **code golf**, so the shortest solution wins.

### Example Output

Here is an example output produced by [this example implementation in Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/bBmMJ/4/)

```
AS,AC,AD,AH,2S,2C,2D,2H,3S,3C,3D,3H,4S,4C,4D,4H,5S,5C,5D,5H,6S,6C,6D,6H,7S,7C,7D,7H,8S,8C,8D,8H,9S,9C,9D,9H,10S,10C,10D,10H,JS,JC,JD,JH,QS,QC,QD,QH,KS,KC,KD,KH
AS,7D,AC,7H,AD,8S,AH,8C,2S,8D,2C,8H,2D,9S,2H,9C,3S,9D,3C,9H,3D,10S,3H,10C,4S,10D,4C,10H,4D,JS,4H,JC,5S,JD,5C,JH,5D,QS,5H,QC,6S,QD,6C,QH,6D,KS,6H,KC,7S,KD,7C,KH
AS,4C,7D,10H,AC,4D,7H,JS,AD,4H,8S,JC,AH,5S,8C,JD,2S,5C,8D,JH,2C,5D,8H,QS,2D,5H,9S,QC,2H,6S,9C,QD,3S,6C,9D,QH,3C,6D,9H,KS,3D,6H,10S,KC,3H,7S,10C,KD,4S,7C,10D,KH
AS,9S,4C,QC,7D,2H,10H,6S,AC,9C,4D,QD,7H,3S,JS,6C,AD,9D,4H,QH,8S,3C,JC,6D,AH,9H,5S,KS,8C,3D,JD,6H,2S,10S,5C,KC,8D,3H,JH,7S,2C,10C,5D,KD,8H,4S,QS,7C,2D,10D,5H,KH 
AS,5S,9S,KS,4C,8C,QC,3D,7D,JD,2H,6H,10H,2S,6S,10S,AC,5C,9C,KC,4D,8D,QD,3H,7H,JH,3S,7S,JS,2C,6C,10C,AD,5D,9D,KD,4H,8H,QH,4S,8S,QS,3C,7C,JC,2D,6D,10D,AH,5H,9H,KH 
AS,3S,5S,7S,9S,JS,KS,2C,4C,6C,8C,10C,QC,AD,3D,5D,7D,9D,JD,KD,2H,4H,6H,8H,10H,QH,2S,4S,6S,8S,10S,QS,AC,3C,5C,7C,9C,JC,KC,2D,4D,6D,8D,10D,QD,AH,3H,5H,7H,9H,JH,KH 
AS,2S,3S,4S,5S,6S,7S,8S,9S,10S,JS,QS,KS,AC,2C,3C,4C,5C,6C,7C,8C,9C,10C,JC,QC,KC,AD,2D,3D,4D,5D,6D,7D,8D,9D,10D,JD,QD,KD,AH,2H,3H,4H,5H,6H,7H,8H,9H,10H,JH,QH,KH 
AS,AD,2S,2D,3S,3D,4S,4D,5S,5D,6S,6D,7S,7D,8S,8D,9S,9D,10S,10D,JS,JD,QS,QD,KS,KD,AC,AH,2C,2H,3C,3H,4C,4H,5C,5H,6C,6H,7C,7H,8C,8H,9C,9H,10C,10H,JC,JH,QC,QH,KC,KH 
AS,AC,AD,AH,2S,2C,2D,2H,3S,3C,3D,3H,4S,4C,4D,4H,5S,5C,5D,5H,6S,6C,6D,6H,7S,7C,7D,7H,8S,8C,8D,8H,9S,9C,9D,9H,10S,10C,10D,10H,JS,JC,JD,JH,QS,QC,QD,QH,KS,KC,KD,KH
```

Comment: Whilst not an exact duplicate, this is essentially about half of the task from [Mix the nuts](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6487/code-golf-mix-the-nuts-so-that-none-of-the-same-kind-are-touching) (at least as implemented by the current answers).

Comment: Is the starting order of the cards important?

Comment: @chron No, the cards can start out in any order.

Answer (score 15):

### J, <strike>66</strike> <strike>65</strike> <strike>54</strike> <strike>52</strike> <strike>50</strike> <strike>47</strike> 43 characters

```
26({.,@,.}.)^:(i.9),{'A23456789TJQK';'SCDH'
```

Output:

```
┌──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┐
│AS│AC│AD│AH│2S│2C│2D│2H│3S│3C│3D│3H│4S│4C│4D│4H│5S│5C│5D│5H│6S│6C│6D│6H│7S│7C│7D│7H│8S│8C│8D│8H│9S│9C│9D│9H│TS│TC│TD│TH│JS│JC│JD│JH│QS│QC│QD│QH│KS│KC│KD│KH│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤
│AS│7D│AC│7H│AD│8S│AH│8C│2S│8D│2C│8H│2D│9S│2H│9C│3S│9D│3C│9H│3D│TS│3H│TC│4S│TD│4C│TH│4D│JS│4H│JC│5S│JD│5C│JH│5D│QS│5H│QC│6S│QD│6C│QH│6D│KS│6H│KC│7S│KD│7C│KH│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤
│AS│4C│7D│TH│AC│4D│7H│JS│AD│4H│8S│JC│AH│5S│8C│JD│2S│5C│8D│JH│2C│5D│8H│QS│2D│5H│9S│QC│2H│6S│9C│QD│3S│6C│9D│QH│3C│6D│9H│KS│3D│6H│TS│KC│3H│7S│TC│KD│4S│7C│TD│KH│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤
│AS│9S│4C│QC│7D│2H│TH│6S│AC│9C│4D│QD│7H│3S│JS│6C│AD│9D│4H│QH│8S│3C│JC│6D│AH│9H│5S│KS│8C│3D│JD│6H│2S│TS│5C│KC│8D│3H│JH│7S│2C│TC│5D│KD│8H│4S│QS│7C│2D│TD│5H│KH│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤
│AS│5S│9S│KS│4C│8C│QC│3D│7D│JD│2H│6H│TH│2S│6S│TS│AC│5C│9C│KC│4D│8D│QD│3H│7H│JH│3S│7S│JS│2C│6C│TC│AD│5D│9D│KD│4H│8H│QH│4S│8S│QS│3C│7C│JC│2D│6D│TD│AH│5H│9H│KH│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤
│AS│3S│5S│7S│9S│JS│KS│2C│4C│6C│8C│TC│QC│AD│3D│5D│7D│9D│JD│KD│2H│4H│6H│8H│TH│QH│2S│4S│6S│8S│TS│QS│AC│3C│5C│7C│9C│JC│KC│2D│4D│6D│8D│TD│QD│AH│3H│5H│7H│9H│JH│KH│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤
│AS│2S│3S│4S│5S│6S│7S│8S│9S│TS│JS│QS│KS│AC│2C│3C│4C│5C│6C│7C│8C│9C│TC│JC│QC│KC│AD│2D│3D│4D│5D│6D│7D│8D│9D│TD│JD│QD│KD│AH│2H│3H│4H│5H│6H│7H│8H│9H│TH│JH│QH│KH│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤
│AS│AD│2S│2D│3S│3D│4S│4D│5S│5D│6S│6D│7S│7D│8S│8D│9S│9D│TS│TD│JS│JD│QS│QD│KS│KD│AC│AH│2C│2H│3C│3H│4C│4H│5C│5H│6C│6H│7C│7H│8C│8H│9C│9H│TC│TH│JC│JH│QC│QH│KC│KH│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┤
│AS│AC│AD│AH│2S│2C│2D│2H│3S│3C│3D│3H│4S│4C│4D│4H│5S│5C│5D│5H│6S│6C│6D│6H│7S│7C│7D│7H│8S│8C│8D│8H│9S│9C│9D│9H│TS│TC│TD│TH│JS│JC│JD│JH│QS│QC│QD│QH│KS│KC│KD│KH│
└──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┘
```

I'm being forced further and further into J's tutorials and reference manuals to stay ahead here. :-S

Comment: Your 1st and last arrays are identical. Moreover, your 1st card is always `AS` and last is all the time `KH`.

Comment: @ArtemIce They're supposed to be. It's required in the question. Re-read the first paragraph.

Comment: @Gareth ok sorry

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 103

```
m(a:s,b:t)=a:b:m(s,t);m _=[]
main=mapM_ putStrLn.take 9.iterate(m.splitAt 26)$take 13.enumFrom=<<""
```

Output:

---

Don't know if there are any UTF-8 problems around here, shouldn't... this is a hex dump of the program

```
0000000 286d 3a61 2c73 3a62 2974 613d 623a 6d3a
0000010 7328 742c 3b29 206d 3d5f 5d5b 6d0a 6961
0000020 3d6e 616d 4d70 205f 7570 5374 7274 6e4c
0000030 742e 6b61 2065 2e39 7469 7265 7461 2865
0000040 2e6d 7073 696c 4174 2074 3632 2429 6174
0000050 656b 3120 2e33 6e65 6d75 7246 6d6f 3c3d
0000060 223c 9ff0 a182 9ff0 9183 9ff0 8183 9ff0
0000070 b182 0a22                              
0000074
```

and of the first output line

```
0000000 9ff0 a182 9ff0 a282 9ff0 a382 9ff0 a482
0000010 9ff0 a582 9ff0 a682 9ff0 a782 9ff0 a882
0000020 9ff0 a982 9ff0 aa82 9ff0 ab82 9ff0 ac82
0000030 9ff0 ad82 9ff0 9183 9ff0 9283 9ff0 9383
0000040 9ff0 9483 9ff0 9583 9ff0 9683 9ff0 9783
0000050 9ff0 9883 9ff0 9983 9ff0 9a83 9ff0 9b83
0000060 9ff0 9c83 9ff0 9d83 9ff0 8183 9ff0 8283
0000070 9ff0 8383 9ff0 8483 9ff0 8583 9ff0 8683
0000080 9ff0 8783 9ff0 8883 9ff0 8983 9ff0 8a83
0000090 9ff0 8b83 9ff0 8c83 9ff0 8d83 9ff0 b182
00000a0 9ff0 b282 9ff0 b382 9ff0 b482 9ff0 b582
00000b0 9ff0 b682 9ff0 b782 9ff0 b882 9ff0 b982
00000c0 9ff0 ba82 9ff0 bb82 9ff0 bc82 9ff0 bd82
00000d0 000a                                   
00000d1
```

(the [unicode playing cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_Cards_%28Unicode_block%29))

Comment: The output is whitespace...

Comment: Erm, no it isn't! What do you mean?

Comment: Ok this is interesting, directly after editing Stack Exchange also shows me whitespace. Weird... after posting this comment it works again, though.

Comment: You lack the font to view such lovely codepoints like ['PLAYING CARD JACK OF CLUBS' (U+1F0DB)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f0db/index.htm).

Answer (score 8):

### Python 2, 79 chars

```
d=zip("23456789TJQKA"*4,"CDHS"*13)
exec'print d;d[::2],d[1::2]=d[:26],d[26:];'*9
```

The output is a bit ugly but I believe it should count.

```
[('2', 'C'), ('3', 'D'), ('4', 'H'), ('5', 'S'), ('6', 'C'), ('7', 'D'), ('8', 'H'), ('9', 'S'), ('T', 'C'), ('J', 'D'), ('Q', 'H'), ('K', 'S'), ('A', 'C'), ('2', 'D'), ('3', 'H'), ('4', 'S'), ('5', 'C'), ('6', 'D'), ('7', 'H'), ('8', 'S'), ('9', 'C'), ('T', 'D'), ('J', 'H'), ('Q', 'S'), ('K', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('2', 'H'), ('3', 'S'), ('4', 'C'), ('5', 'D'), ('6', 'H'), ('7', 'S'), ('8', 'C'), ('9', 'D'), ('T', 'H'), ('J', 'S'), ('Q', 'C'), ('K', 'D'), ('A', 'H'), ('2', 'S'), ('3', 'C'), ('4', 'D'), ('5', 'H'), ('6', 'S'), ('7', 'C'), ('8', 'D'), ('9', 'H'), ('T', 'S'), ('J', 'C'), ('Q', 'D'), ('K', 'H'), ('A', 'S')]
[('2', 'C'), ('2', 'H'), ('3', 'D'), ('3', 'S'), ('4', 'H'), ('4', 'C'), ('5', 'S'), ('5', 'D'), ('6', 'C'), ('6', 'H'), ('7', 'D'), ('7', 'S'), ('8', 'H'), ('8', 'C'), ('9', 'S'), ('9', 'D'), ('T', 'C'), ('T', 'H'), ('J', 'D'), ('J', 'S'), ('Q', 'H'), ('Q', 'C'), ('K', 'S'), ('K', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'H'), ('2', 'D'), ('2', 'S'), ('3', 'H'), ('3', 'C'), ('4', 'S'), ('4', 'D'), ('5', 'C'), ('5', 'H'), ('6', 'D'), ('6', 'S'), ('7', 'H'), ('7', 'C'), ('8', 'S'), ('8', 'D'), ('9', 'C'), ('9', 'H'), ('T', 'D'), ('T', 'S'), ('J', 'H'), ('J', 'C'), ('Q', 'S'), ('Q', 'D'), ('K', 'C'), ('K', 'H'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'S')]
[('2', 'C'), ('2', 'D'), ('2', 'H'), ('2', 'S'), ('3', 'D'), ('3', 'H'), ('3', 'S'), ('3', 'C'), ('4', 'H'), ('4', 'S'), ('4', 'C'), ('4', 'D'), ('5', 'S'), ('5', 'C'), ('5', 'D'), ('5', 'H'), ('6', 'C'), ('6', 'D'), ('6', 'H'), ('6', 'S'), ('7', 'D'), ('7', 'H'), ('7', 'S'), ('7', 'C'), ('8', 'H'), ('8', 'S'), ('8', 'C'), ('8', 'D'), ('9', 'S'), ('9', 'C'), ('9', 'D'), ('9', 'H'), ('T', 'C'), ('T', 'D'), ('T', 'H'), ('T', 'S'), ('J', 'D'), ('J', 'H'), ('J', 'S'), ('J', 'C'), ('Q', 'H'), ('Q', 'S'), ('Q', 'C'), ('Q', 'D'), ('K', 'S'), ('K', 'C'), ('K', 'D'), ('K', 'H'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'H'), ('A', 'S')]
[('2', 'C'), ('8', 'C'), ('2', 'D'), ('8', 'D'), ('2', 'H'), ('9', 'S'), ('2', 'S'), ('9', 'C'), ('3', 'D'), ('9', 'D'), ('3', 'H'), ('9', 'H'), ('3', 'S'), ('T', 'C'), ('3', 'C'), ('T', 'D'), ('4', 'H'), ('T', 'H'), ('4', 'S'), ('T', 'S'), ('4', 'C'), ('J', 'D'), ('4', 'D'), ('J', 'H'), ('5', 'S'), ('J', 'S'), ('5', 'C'), ('J', 'C'), ('5', 'D'), ('Q', 'H'), ('5', 'H'), ('Q', 'S'), ('6', 'C'), ('Q', 'C'), ('6', 'D'), ('Q', 'D'), ('6', 'H'), ('K', 'S'), ('6', 'S'), ('K', 'C'), ('7', 'D'), ('K', 'D'), ('7', 'H'), ('K', 'H'), ('7', 'S'), ('A', 'C'), ('7', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('8', 'H'), ('A', 'H'), ('8', 'S'), ('A', 'S')]
[('2', 'C'), ('5', 'C'), ('8', 'C'), ('J', 'C'), ('2', 'D'), ('5', 'D'), ('8', 'D'), ('Q', 'H'), ('2', 'H'), ('5', 'H'), ('9', 'S'), ('Q', 'S'), ('2', 'S'), ('6', 'C'), ('9', 'C'), ('Q', 'C'), ('3', 'D'), ('6', 'D'), ('9', 'D'), ('Q', 'D'), ('3', 'H'), ('6', 'H'), ('9', 'H'), ('K', 'S'), ('3', 'S'), ('6', 'S'), ('T', 'C'), ('K', 'C'), ('3', 'C'), ('7', 'D'), ('T', 'D'), ('K', 'D'), ('4', 'H'), ('7', 'H'), ('T', 'H'), ('K', 'H'), ('4', 'S'), ('7', 'S'), ('T', 'S'), ('A', 'C'), ('4', 'C'), ('7', 'C'), ('J', 'D'), ('A', 'D'), ('4', 'D'), ('8', 'H'), ('J', 'H'), ('A', 'H'), ('5', 'S'), ('8', 'S'), ('J', 'S'), ('A', 'S')]
[('2', 'C'), ('T', 'C'), ('5', 'C'), ('K', 'C'), ('8', 'C'), ('3', 'C'), ('J', 'C'), ('7', 'D'), ('2', 'D'), ('T', 'D'), ('5', 'D'), ('K', 'D'), ('8', 'D'), ('4', 'H'), ('Q', 'H'), ('7', 'H'), ('2', 'H'), ('T', 'H'), ('5', 'H'), ('K', 'H'), ('9', 'S'), ('4', 'S'), ('Q', 'S'), ('7', 'S'), ('2', 'S'), ('T', 'S'), ('6', 'C'), ('A', 'C'), ('9', 'C'), ('4', 'C'), ('Q', 'C'), ('7', 'C'), ('3', 'D'), ('J', 'D'), ('6', 'D'), ('A', 'D'), ('9', 'D'), ('4', 'D'), ('Q', 'D'), ('8', 'H'), ('3', 'H'), ('J', 'H'), ('6', 'H'), ('A', 'H'), ('9', 'H'), ('5', 'S'), ('K', 'S'), ('8', 'S'), ('3', 'S'), ('J', 'S'), ('6', 'S'), ('A', 'S')]
[('2', 'C'), ('6', 'C'), ('T', 'C'), ('A', 'C'), ('5', 'C'), ('9', 'C'), ('K', 'C'), ('4', 'C'), ('8', 'C'), ('Q', 'C'), ('3', 'C'), ('7', 'C'), ('J', 'C'), ('3', 'D'), ('7', 'D'), ('J', 'D'), ('2', 'D'), ('6', 'D'), ('T', 'D'), ('A', 'D'), ('5', 'D'), ('9', 'D'), ('K', 'D'), ('4', 'D'), ('8', 'D'), ('Q', 'D'), ('4', 'H'), ('8', 'H'), ('Q', 'H'), ('3', 'H'), ('7', 'H'), ('J', 'H'), ('2', 'H'), ('6', 'H'), ('T', 'H'), ('A', 'H'), ('5', 'H'), ('9', 'H'), ('K', 'H'), ('5', 'S'), ('9', 'S'), ('K', 'S'), ('4', 'S'), ('8', 'S'), ('Q', 'S'), ('3', 'S'), ('7', 'S'), ('J', 'S'), ('2', 'S'), ('6', 'S'), ('T', 'S'), ('A', 'S')]
[('2', 'C'), ('4', 'H'), ('6', 'C'), ('8', 'H'), ('T', 'C'), ('Q', 'H'), ('A', 'C'), ('3', 'H'), ('5', 'C'), ('7', 'H'), ('9', 'C'), ('J', 'H'), ('K', 'C'), ('2', 'H'), ('4', 'C'), ('6', 'H'), ('8', 'C'), ('T', 'H'), ('Q', 'C'), ('A', 'H'), ('3', 'C'), ('5', 'H'), ('7', 'C'), ('9', 'H'), ('J', 'C'), ('K', 'H'), ('3', 'D'), ('5', 'S'), ('7', 'D'), ('9', 'S'), ('J', 'D'), ('K', 'S'), ('2', 'D'), ('4', 'S'), ('6', 'D'), ('8', 'S'), ('T', 'D'), ('Q', 'S'), ('A', 'D'), ('3', 'S'), ('5', 'D'), ('7', 'S'), ('9', 'D'), ('J', 'S'), ('K', 'D'), ('2', 'S'), ('4', 'D'), ('6', 'S'), ('8', 'D'), ('T', 'S'), ('Q', 'D'), ('A', 'S')]
[('2', 'C'), ('3', 'D'), ('4', 'H'), ('5', 'S'), ('6', 'C'), ('7', 'D'), ('8', 'H'), ('9', 'S'), ('T', 'C'), ('J', 'D'), ('Q', 'H'), ('K', 'S'), ('A', 'C'), ('2', 'D'), ('3', 'H'), ('4', 'S'), ('5', 'C'), ('6', 'D'), ('7', 'H'), ('8', 'S'), ('9', 'C'), ('T', 'D'), ('J', 'H'), ('Q', 'S'), ('K', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('2', 'H'), ('3', 'S'), ('4', 'C'), ('5', 'D'), ('6', 'H'), ('7', 'S'), ('8', 'C'), ('9', 'D'), ('T', 'H'), ('J', 'S'), ('Q', 'C'), ('K', 'D'), ('A', 'H'), ('2', 'S'), ('3', 'C'), ('4', 'D'), ('5', 'H'), ('6', 'S'), ('7', 'C'), ('8', 'D'), ('9', 'H'), ('T', 'S'), ('J', 'C'), ('Q', 'D'), ('K', 'H'), ('A', 'S')]
```

Comment: nice `product`!

Answer (score 6):

### Python2, 104

This is similar to Ev_Genus's solution.  I put suit before rank because it enables me to save a character.

```
d=[s+[r,`10`][r>"Q"]for r in'A23456789ZJQK'for s in"SCDH"]
exec'print d;d=sum(zip(d[:26],d[26:]),());'*9
```

**Output**

```
['SA', 'CA', 'DA', 'HA', 'S2', 'C2', 'D2', 'H2', 'S3', 'C3', 'D3', 'H3', 'S4', 'C4', 'D4', 'H4', 'S5', 'C5', 'D5', 'H5', 'S6', 'C6', 'D6', 'H6', 'S7', 'C7', 'D7', 'H7', 'S8', 'C8', 'D8', 'H8', 'S9', 'C9', 'D9', 'H9', 'S10', 'C10', 'D10', 'H10', 'SJ', 'CJ', 'DJ', 'HJ', 'SQ', 'CQ', 'DQ', 'HQ', 'SK', 'CK', 'DK', 'HK']
('SA', 'D7', 'CA', 'H7', 'DA', 'S8', 'HA', 'C8', 'S2', 'D8', 'C2', 'H8', 'D2', 'S9', 'H2', 'C9', 'S3', 'D9', 'C3', 'H9', 'D3', 'S10', 'H3', 'C10', 'S4', 'D10', 'C4', 'H10', 'D4', 'SJ', 'H4', 'CJ', 'S5', 'DJ', 'C5', 'HJ', 'D5', 'SQ', 'H5', 'CQ', 'S6', 'DQ', 'C6', 'HQ', 'D6', 'SK', 'H6', 'CK', 'S7', 'DK', 'C7', 'HK')
('SA', 'C4', 'D7', 'H10', 'CA', 'D4', 'H7', 'SJ', 'DA', 'H4', 'S8', 'CJ', 'HA', 'S5', 'C8', 'DJ', 'S2', 'C5', 'D8', 'HJ', 'C2', 'D5', 'H8', 'SQ', 'D2', 'H5', 'S9', 'CQ', 'H2', 'S6', 'C9', 'DQ', 'S3', 'C6', 'D9', 'HQ', 'C3', 'D6', 'H9', 'SK', 'D3', 'H6', 'S10', 'CK', 'H3', 'S7', 'C10', 'DK', 'S4', 'C7', 'D10', 'HK')
('SA', 'S9', 'C4', 'CQ', 'D7', 'H2', 'H10', 'S6', 'CA', 'C9', 'D4', 'DQ', 'H7', 'S3', 'SJ', 'C6', 'DA', 'D9', 'H4', 'HQ', 'S8', 'C3', 'CJ', 'D6', 'HA', 'H9', 'S5', 'SK', 'C8', 'D3', 'DJ', 'H6', 'S2', 'S10', 'C5', 'CK', 'D8', 'H3', 'HJ', 'S7', 'C2', 'C10', 'D5', 'DK', 'H8', 'S4', 'SQ', 'C7', 'D2', 'D10', 'H5', 'HK')
('SA', 'S5', 'S9', 'SK', 'C4', 'C8', 'CQ', 'D3', 'D7', 'DJ', 'H2', 'H6', 'H10', 'S2', 'S6', 'S10', 'CA', 'C5', 'C9', 'CK', 'D4', 'D8', 'DQ', 'H3', 'H7', 'HJ', 'S3', 'S7', 'SJ', 'C2', 'C6', 'C10', 'DA', 'D5', 'D9', 'DK', 'H4', 'H8', 'HQ', 'S4', 'S8', 'SQ', 'C3', 'C7', 'CJ', 'D2', 'D6', 'D10', 'HA', 'H5', 'H9', 'HK')
('SA', 'S3', 'S5', 'S7', 'S9', 'SJ', 'SK', 'C2', 'C4', 'C6', 'C8', 'C10', 'CQ', 'DA', 'D3', 'D5', 'D7', 'D9', 'DJ', 'DK', 'H2', 'H4', 'H6', 'H8', 'H10', 'HQ', 'S2', 'S4', 'S6', 'S8', 'S10', 'SQ', 'CA', 'C3', 'C5', 'C7', 'C9', 'CJ', 'CK', 'D2', 'D4', 'D6', 'D8', 'D10', 'DQ', 'HA', 'H3', 'H5', 'H7', 'H9', 'HJ', 'HK')
('SA', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'S10', 'SJ', 'SQ', 'SK', 'CA', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'CJ', 'CQ', 'CK', 'DA', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'D10', 'DJ', 'DQ', 'DK', 'HA', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7', 'H8', 'H9', 'H10', 'HJ', 'HQ', 'HK')
('SA', 'DA', 'S2', 'D2', 'S3', 'D3', 'S4', 'D4', 'S5', 'D5', 'S6', 'D6', 'S7', 'D7', 'S8', 'D8', 'S9', 'D9', 'S10', 'D10', 'SJ', 'DJ', 'SQ', 'DQ', 'SK', 'DK', 'CA', 'HA', 'C2', 'H2', 'C3', 'H3', 'C4', 'H4', 'C5', 'H5', 'C6', 'H6', 'C7', 'H7', 'C8', 'H8', 'C9', 'H9', 'C10', 'H10', 'CJ', 'HJ', 'CQ', 'HQ', 'CK', 'HK')
('SA', 'CA', 'DA', 'HA', 'S2', 'C2', 'D2', 'H2', 'S3', 'C3', 'D3', 'H3', 'S4', 'C4', 'D4', 'H4', 'S5', 'C5', 'D5', 'H5', 'S6', 'C6', 'D6', 'H6', 'S7', 'C7', 'D7', 'H7', 'S8', 'C8', 'D8', 'H8', 'S9', 'C9', 'D9', 'H9', 'S10', 'C10', 'D10', 'H10', 'SJ', 'CJ', 'DJ', 'HJ', 'SQ', 'CQ', 'DQ', 'HQ', 'SK', 'CK', 'DK', 'HK')
```

Comment: +1.  `[r,'10'][r>"Q"]` is nifty.  I don't think you need backticks around the `10`.  Quotes would do fine.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, I used backticks for the lulz.  Quotes take the same amount of space.

Comment: If it were allowable (it isn't) to have the results in reverse order, this would work: `exec'print d;d=d[::2]+d[1::2];'*9`.

Comment: Shame to me. I've forgot about `sum`.

Answer (score 6):

### APL (42)

```
{↑{⍉2 26⍴⍵}⍣⍵,'A23456789TJQK'∘.,'SCDH'}¨⍳9
```

Output is top-down instead of left-right (but it's still human readable so I guess it's not against the rules).

Output:

```
 AS  AS  AS  AS  AS  AS  AS  AS  AS 
 7D  4C  9S  5S  3S  2S  AD  AC  7D 

 AC  7D  4C  9S  5S  3S  2S  AD  AC 
 7H  TH  QC  KS  7S  4S  2D  AH  7H 

 AD  AC  7D  4C  9S  5S  3S  2S  AD 
 8S  4D  2H  8C  JS  6S  3D  2C  8S 

 AH  7H  TH  QC  KS  7S  4S  2D  AH 
 8C  JS  6S  3D  2C  8S  4D  2H  8C 

 2S  AD  AC  7D  4C  9S  5S  3S  2S 
 8D  4H  9C  JD  6C  TS  5D  3C  8D 

 2C  8S  4D  2H  8C  JS  6S  3D  2C 
 8H  JC  QD  6H  TC  QS  6D  3H  8H 

 2D  AH  7H  TH  QC  KS  7S  4S  2D 
 9S  5S  3S  2S  AD  AC  7D  4C  9S 

 2H  8C  JS  6S  3D  2C  8S  4D  2H 
 9C  JD  6C  TS  5D  3C  8D  4H  9C 

 3S  2S  AD  AC  7D  4C  9S  5S  3S 
 9D  5C  9D  5C  9D  5C  9D  5C  9D 

 3C  8D  4H  9C  JD  6C  TS  5D  3C 
 9H  JH  QH  KC  KD  7C  TD  5H  9H 

 3D  2C  8S  4D  2H  8C  JS  6S  3D 
 TS  5D  3C  8D  4H  9C  JD  6C  TS 

 3H  8H  JC  QD  6H  TC  QS  6D  3H 
 TC  QS  6D  3H  8H  JC  QD  6H  TC 

 4S  2D  AH  7H  TH  QC  KS  7S  4S 
 TD  5H  9H  JH  QH  KC  KD  7C  TD 

 4C  9S  5S  3S  2S  AD  AC  7D  4C 
 TH  QC  KS  7S  4S  2D  AH  7H  TH 

 4D  2H  8C  JS  6S  3D  2C  8S  4D 
 JS  6S  3D  2C  8S  4D  2H  8C  JS 

 4H  9C  JD  6C  TS  5D  3C  8D  4H 
 JC  QD  6H  TC  QS  6D  3H  8H  JC 

 5S  3S  2S  AD  AC  7D  4C  9S  5S 
 JD  6C  TS  5D  3C  8D  4H  9C  JD 

 5C  9D  5C  9D  5C  9D  5C  9D  5C 
 JH  QH  KC  KD  7C  TD  5H  9H  JH 

 5D  3C  8D  4H  9C  JD  6C  TS  5D 
 QS  6D  3H  8H  JC  QD  6H  TC  QS 

 5H  9H  JH  QH  KC  KD  7C  TD  5H 
 QC  KS  7S  4S  2D  AH  7H  TH  QC 

 6S  3D  2C  8S  4D  2H  8C  JS  6S 
 QD  6H  TC  QS  6D  3H  8H  JC  QD 

 6C  TS  5D  3C  8D  4H  9C  JD  6C 
 QH  KC  KD  7C  TD  5H  9H  JH  QH 

 6D  3H  8H  JC  QD  6H  TC  QS  6D 
 KS  7S  4S  2D  AH  7H  TH  QC  KS 

 6H  TC  QS  6D  3H  8H  JC  QD  6H 
 KC  KD  7C  TD  5H  9H  JH  QH  KC 

 7S  4S  2D  AH  7H  TH  QC  KS  7S 
 KD  7C  TD  5H  9H  JH  QH  KC  KD 

 7C  TD  5H  9H  JH  QH  KC  KD  7C 
 KH  KH  KH  KH  KH  KH  KH  KH  KH
```

Answer (score 5):

## K, <strike>55</strike> <strike>53</strike> 51

```
{$,/(,').`$2 26#x}\[8;,/"A23456789TJQK",/:\:"SCDH"]
```

Shaved 2 chars by changing from symbol representation to string

output

```
k){$,/(,').`$(2 26)#x}\[8;,/"A23456789TJQK",/:\:"SCDH"]
"AS" "AC" "AD" "AH" "2S" "2C" "2D" "2H" "3S" "3C" "3D" "3H" "4S" "4C" "4D" "4H" "5S" "5C" "5D" "5H" "6S" "6C" "6D" "6H" "7S" "7C" "7D" "7H" "8S" "8C" "8D" "8H" "9S" "9C" "9D" "9H" "TS" "TC" "TD" "TH" "JS" "JC" "JD" "JH" "QS" "QC" "QD" "QH" "KS" "KC" "KD" "KH"
"AS" "7D" "AC" "7H" "AD" "8S" "AH" "8C" "2S" "8D" "2C" "8H" "2D" "9S" "2H" "9C" "3S" "9D" "3C" "9H" "3D" "TS" "3H" "TC" "4S" "TD" "4C" "TH" "4D" "JS" "4H" "JC" "5S" "JD" "5C" "JH" "5D" "QS" "5H" "QC" "6S" "QD" "6C" "QH" "6D" "KS" "6H" "KC" "7S" "KD" "7C" "KH"
"AS" "4C" "7D" "TH" "AC" "4D" "7H" "JS" "AD" "4H" "8S" "JC" "AH" "5S" "8C" "JD" "2S" "5C" "8D" "JH" "2C" "5D" "8H" "QS" "2D" "5H" "9S" "QC" "2H" "6S" "9C" "QD" "3S" "6C" "9D" "QH" "3C" "6D" "9H" "KS" "3D" "6H" "TS" "KC" "3H" "7S" "TC" "KD" "4S" "7C" "TD" "KH"
"AS" "9S" "4C" "QC" "7D" "2H" "TH" "6S" "AC" "9C" "4D" "QD" "7H" "3S" "JS" "6C" "AD" "9D" "4H" "QH" "8S" "3C" "JC" "6D" "AH" "9H" "5S" "KS" "8C" "3D" "JD" "6H" "2S" "TS" "5C" "KC" "8D" "3H" "JH" "7S" "2C" "TC" "5D" "KD" "8H" "4S" "QS" "7C" "2D" "TD" "5H" "KH"
"AS" "5S" "9S" "KS" "4C" "8C" "QC" "3D" "7D" "JD" "2H" "6H" "TH" "2S" "6S" "TS" "AC" "5C" "9C" "KC" "4D" "8D" "QD" "3H" "7H" "JH" "3S" "7S" "JS" "2C" "6C" "TC" "AD" "5D" "9D" "KD" "4H" "8H" "QH" "4S" "8S" "QS" "3C" "7C" "JC" "2D" "6D" "TD" "AH" "5H" "9H" "KH"
"AS" "3S" "5S" "7S" "9S" "JS" "KS" "2C" "4C" "6C" "8C" "TC" "QC" "AD" "3D" "5D" "7D" "9D" "JD" "KD" "2H" "4H" "6H" "8H" "TH" "QH" "2S" "4S" "6S" "8S" "TS" "QS" "AC" "3C" "5C" "7C" "9C" "JC" "KC" "2D" "4D" "6D" "8D" "TD" "QD" "AH" "3H" "5H" "7H" "9H" "JH" "KH"
"AS" "2S" "3S" "4S" "5S" "6S" "7S" "8S" "9S" "TS" "JS" "QS" "KS" "AC" "2C" "3C" "4C" "5C" "6C" "7C" "8C" "9C" "TC" "JC" "QC" "KC" "AD" "2D" "3D" "4D" "5D" "6D" "7D" "8D" "9D" "TD" "JD" "QD" "KD" "AH" "2H" "3H" "4H" "5H" "6H" "7H" "8H" "9H" "TH" "JH" "QH" "KH"
"AS" "AD" "2S" "2D" "3S" "3D" "4S" "4D" "5S" "5D" "6S" "6D" "7S" "7D" "8S" "8D" "9S" "9D" "TS" "TD" "JS" "JD" "QS" "QD" "KS" "KD" "AC" "AH" "2C" "2H" "3C" "3H" "4C" "4H" "5C" "5H" "6C" "6H" "7C" "7H" "8C" "8H" "9C" "9H" "TC" "TH" "JC" "JH" "QC" "QH" "KC" "KH"
"AS" "AC" "AD" "AH" "2S" "2C" "2D" "2H" "3S" "3C" "3D" "3H" "4S" "4C" "4D" "4H" "5S" "5C" "5D" "5H" "6S" "6C" "6D" "6H" "7S" "7C" "7D" "7H" "8S" "8C" "8D" "8H" "9S" "9C" "9D" "9H" "TS" "TC" "TD" "TH" "JS" "JC" "JD" "JH" "QS" "QC" "QD" "QH" "KS" "KC" "KD" "KH"

k)@[a;0]~@[;8]a:{$,/(,').`$(2 26)#x}\[8;,/"A23456789TJQK",/:\:"SCDH"]  /8th iteration identical to the first?
1b
```

Comment: You can cut a further 2 chars (and beat J) by changing `(2;26)` to `2 26`

Comment: Excellent. I've been having an ongoing battle with that J solution. 65-55-54-53-52-51

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby 1.9 (<del>95</del> <del>93</del> 87)

```ruby
a=(0..51).map{|i|:A23456789TJQK[i/4]+:SCDH[i%4]}
9.times{p a;a=a.zip(a.pop 26).flatten}
```

Output:

```
["AS", "AC", "AD", "AH", "2S", "2C", "2D", "2H", "3S", "3C", "3D", "3H", "4S", "4C", "4D", "4H", "5S", "5C", "5D", "5H", "6S", "6C", "6D", "6H", "7S", "7C", "7D", "7H", "8S", "8C", "8D", "8H", "9S", "9C", "9D", "9H", "TS", "TC", "TD", "TH", "JS", "JC", "JD", "JH", "QS", "QC", "QD", "QH", "KS", "KC", "KD", "KH"]
["AS", "7D", "AC", "7H", "AD", "8S", "AH", "8C", "2S", "8D", "2C", "8H", "2D", "9S", "2H", "9C", "3S", "9D", "3C", "9H", "3D", "TS", "3H", "TC", "4S", "TD", "4C", "TH", "4D", "JS", "4H", "JC", "5S", "JD", "5C", "JH", "5D", "QS", "5H", "QC", "6S", "QD", "6C", "QH", "6D", "KS", "6H", "KC", "7S", "KD", "7C", "KH"]
["AS", "4C", "7D", "TH", "AC", "4D", "7H", "JS", "AD", "4H", "8S", "JC", "AH", "5S", "8C", "JD", "2S", "5C", "8D", "JH", "2C", "5D", "8H", "QS", "2D", "5H", "9S", "QC", "2H", "6S", "9C", "QD", "3S", "6C", "9D", "QH", "3C", "6D", "9H", "KS", "3D", "6H", "TS", "KC", "3H", "7S", "TC", "KD", "4S", "7C", "TD", "KH"]
["AS", "9S", "4C", "QC", "7D", "2H", "TH", "6S", "AC", "9C", "4D", "QD", "7H", "3S", "JS", "6C", "AD", "9D", "4H", "QH", "8S", "3C", "JC", "6D", "AH", "9H", "5S", "KS", "8C", "3D", "JD", "6H", "2S", "TS", "5C", "KC", "8D", "3H", "JH", "7S", "2C", "TC", "5D", "KD", "8H", "4S", "QS", "7C", "2D", "TD", "5H", "KH"]
["AS", "5S", "9S", "KS", "4C", "8C", "QC", "3D", "7D", "JD", "2H", "6H", "TH", "2S", "6S", "TS", "AC", "5C", "9C", "KC", "4D", "8D", "QD", "3H", "7H", "JH", "3S", "7S", "JS", "2C", "6C", "TC", "AD", "5D", "9D", "KD", "4H", "8H", "QH", "4S", "8S", "QS", "3C", "7C", "JC", "2D", "6D", "TD", "AH", "5H", "9H", "KH"]
["AS", "3S", "5S", "7S", "9S", "JS", "KS", "2C", "4C", "6C", "8C", "TC", "QC", "AD", "3D", "5D", "7D", "9D", "JD", "KD", "2H", "4H", "6H", "8H", "TH", "QH", "2S", "4S", "6S", "8S", "TS", "QS", "AC", "3C", "5C", "7C", "9C", "JC", "KC", "2D", "4D", "6D", "8D", "TD", "QD", "AH", "3H", "5H", "7H", "9H", "JH", "KH"]
["AS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "TS", "JS", "QS", "KS", "AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "TC", "JC", "QC", "KC", "AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "TD", "JD", "QD", "KD", "AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "TH", "JH", "QH", "KH"]
["AS", "AD", "2S", "2D", "3S", "3D", "4S", "4D", "5S", "5D", "6S", "6D", "7S", "7D", "8S", "8D", "9S", "9D", "TS", "TD", "JS", "JD", "QS", "QD", "KS", "KD", "AC", "AH", "2C", "2H", "3C", "3H", "4C", "4H", "5C", "5H", "6C", "6H", "7C", "7H", "8C", "8H", "9C", "9H", "TC", "TH", "JC", "JH", "QC", "QH", "KC", "KH"]
["AS", "AC", "AD", "AH", "2S", "2C", "2D", "2H", "3S", "3C", "3D", "3H", "4S", "4C", "4D", "4H", "5S", "5C", "5D", "5H", "6S", "6C", "6D", "6H", "7S", "7C", "7D", "7H", "8S", "8C", "8D", "8H", "9S", "9C", "9D", "9H", "TS", "TC", "TD", "TH", "JS", "JC", "JD", "JH", "QS", "QC", "QD", "QH", "KS", "KC", "KD", "KH"]
```

Comment: Symbols instead of strings will save you 2 characters `a=(0..51).map{|i|:A23456789TJQK[i/4]+:SCDH[i%4]}`

Comment: @ArtemIce Good call, for some reason I thought I had tried that unsuccessfully already.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You are welcome! One more idea is that we can use `pop` instead of `slice!` and save 6 characters. `9.times{p a;a=a.zip(a.pop 26).flatten}`

Answer (score 3):

#### Python3, <strike>180</strike> 179

```
from itertools import*;i=list(map("".join,product("A23456789XJQK","SCDH")));exec('print(",".join(i).replace("X","10"));i=list(chain(*zip(islice(i,0,26,1),islice(i,26,52,1))));'*8)
```

Outputs lines like in task.

#### Native Format 151

```
from itertools import*;i=list(map("".join,product("A23456789TJQK","SCDH")));exec('print(i);i=list(chain(*zip(islice(i,0,26,1),islice(i,26,52,1))));'*8)
```

Output is like in Ruby version.

Comment: I think you can save a char by dropping the space between `import` and `*`: http://ideone.com/kQTbs

Comment: If you use 2.x, you should be able to drop the first list(), since map() returns a list not a generator.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <strike>131</strike> <strike>129</strike> <strike>120</strike> <strike>114</strike> <strike>100</strike> 86 chars

With help from Mr.Wizard:

```
NestList[Riffle @@ #~Partition~26 &, # <> "" & /@ Tuples@Characters@
{"A23456789TJQK", "HDCS"}, 8]
```

Output:

[image: shuffles]

Comment: MrWizard suggests reducing this to 86 chars as `NestList[Riffle@@#~Partition~26&,#<>""&/@Tuples@Characters@{"A23456789TJQK","HDCS"},8]`

Comment: I did. Very nice streamlining. I especially liked the trick to reduce `StringJoin`.

Answer (score 3):

#### GolfScript, <strike>51</strike> <strike>50</strike> 46 characters

```
"A23456789TJQK"4*"SCDH"13*]{zip""*2/.p 26/}9*;
```

This GolfScript code yields the following output (see [here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IkEyMzQ1Njc4OVRKUUsiNCoiU0NESCIxMypde3ppcCIiKjIvLnAgMjYvfTkqOw%3D%3D)):

```
["AS" "2C" "3D" "4H" "5S" "6C" "7D" "8H" "9S" "TC" "JD" "QH" "KS" "AC" "2D" "3H" "4S" "5C" "6D" "7H" "8S" "9C" "TD" "JH" "QS" "KC" "AD" "2H" "3S" "4C" "5D" "6H" "7S" "8C" "9D" "TH" "JS" "QC" "KD" "AH" "2S" "3C" "4D" "5H" "6S" "7C" "8D" "9H" "TS" "JC" "QD" "KH"]
["AS" "AD" "2C" "2H" "3D" "3S" "4H" "4C" "5S" "5D" "6C" "6H" "7D" "7S" "8H" "8C" "9S" "9D" "TC" "TH" "JD" "JS" "QH" "QC" "KS" "KD" "AC" "AH" "2D" "2S" "3H" "3C" "4S" "4D" "5C" "5H" "6D" "6S" "7H" "7C" "8S" "8D" "9C" "9H" "TD" "TS" "JH" "JC" "QS" "QD" "KC" "KH"]
["AS" "AC" "AD" "AH" "2C" "2D" "2H" "2S" "3D" "3H" "3S" "3C" "4H" "4S" "4C" "4D" "5S" "5C" "5D" "5H" "6C" "6D" "6H" "6S" "7D" "7H" "7S" "7C" "8H" "8S" "8C" "8D" "9S" "9C" "9D" "9H" "TC" "TD" "TH" "TS" "JD" "JH" "JS" "JC" "QH" "QS" "QC" "QD" "KS" "KC" "KD" "KH"]
["AS" "7S" "AC" "7C" "AD" "8H" "AH" "8S" "2C" "8C" "2D" "8D" "2H" "9S" "2S" "9C" "3D" "9D" "3H" "9H" "3S" "TC" "3C" "TD" "4H" "TH" "4S" "TS" "4C" "JD" "4D" "JH" "5S" "JS" "5C" "JC" "5D" "QH" "5H" "QS" "6C" "QC" "6D" "QD" "6H" "KS" "6S" "KC" "7D" "KD" "7H" "KH"]
["AS" "4S" "7S" "TS" "AC" "4C" "7C" "JD" "AD" "4D" "8H" "JH" "AH" "5S" "8S" "JS" "2C" "5C" "8C" "JC" "2D" "5D" "8D" "QH" "2H" "5H" "9S" "QS" "2S" "6C" "9C" "QC" "3D" "6D" "9D" "QD" "3H" "6H" "9H" "KS" "3S" "6S" "TC" "KC" "3C" "7D" "TD" "KD" "4H" "7H" "TH" "KH"]
["AS" "9S" "4S" "QS" "7S" "2S" "TS" "6C" "AC" "9C" "4C" "QC" "7C" "3D" "JD" "6D" "AD" "9D" "4D" "QD" "8H" "3H" "JH" "6H" "AH" "9H" "5S" "KS" "8S" "3S" "JS" "6S" "2C" "TC" "5C" "KC" "8C" "3C" "JC" "7D" "2D" "TD" "5D" "KD" "8D" "4H" "QH" "7H" "2H" "TH" "5H" "KH"]
["AS" "5S" "9S" "KS" "4S" "8S" "QS" "3S" "7S" "JS" "2S" "6S" "TS" "2C" "6C" "TC" "AC" "5C" "9C" "KC" "4C" "8C" "QC" "3C" "7C" "JC" "3D" "7D" "JD" "2D" "6D" "TD" "AD" "5D" "9D" "KD" "4D" "8D" "QD" "4H" "8H" "QH" "3H" "7H" "JH" "2H" "6H" "TH" "AH" "5H" "9H" "KH"]
["AS" "3D" "5S" "7D" "9S" "JD" "KS" "2D" "4S" "6D" "8S" "TD" "QS" "AD" "3S" "5D" "7S" "9D" "JS" "KD" "2S" "4D" "6S" "8D" "TS" "QD" "2C" "4H" "6C" "8H" "TC" "QH" "AC" "3H" "5C" "7H" "9C" "JH" "KC" "2H" "4C" "6H" "8C" "TH" "QC" "AH" "3C" "5H" "7C" "9H" "JC" "KH"]
["AS" "2C" "3D" "4H" "5S" "6C" "7D" "8H" "9S" "TC" "JD" "QH" "KS" "AC" "2D" "3H" "4S" "5C" "6D" "7H" "8S" "9C" "TD" "JH" "QS" "KC" "AD" "2H" "3S" "4C" "5D" "6H" "7S" "8C" "9D" "TH" "JS" "QC" "KD" "AH" "2S" "3C" "4D" "5H" "6S" "7C" "8D" "9H" "TS" "JC" "QD" "KH"]
```

Comment: Since the cards can start in any order, and since gcd(13, 4) = 1, you can replace `{...}%` by `4*`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you. Didn't read that "in any order" comment.

Answer (score 3):

#### Perl, 91 chars

Any suggestions on a more concise way of building the initial deck? My approach uses 2 substitutions to build `$_` and then a global match in list context to initialize `@_`.

The shuffling is then done by repeatedly `splice`ing `@_` onto `@a` and interleaving the two lists with `map` back into `@_`.

```
s//A23456789TJQK/,s/(.)/$1S$1C$1D$1H/g,@_=/../g;say@_=map{shift@_,$_}@a=splice@_,26for 0..8
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 34 bytes

CJam is newer than the question, so this answer doesn't compete for the green checkmark, but I thought this would be a nice problem to try in CJam.

```
A,2>s"TJQKA"+"SCDH"m*{_p26/z:~}8*p
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

It prints the output like

```
["2S" "2C" "2D" "2H" "3S" "3C" "3D" "3H" "4S" "4C" "4D" "4H" "5S" "5C" "5D" "5H" "6S" "6C" "6D" "6H" "7S" "7C" "7D" "7H" "8S" "8C" "8D" "8H" "9S" "9C" "9D" "9H" "TS" "TC" "TD" "TH" "JS" "JC" "JD" "JH" "QS" "QC" "QD" "QH" "KS" "KC" "KD" "KH" "AS" "AC" "AD" "AH"]
["2S" "8D" "2C" "8H" "2D" "9S" "2H" "9C" "3S" "9D" "3C" "9H" "3D" "TS" "3H" "TC" "4S" "TD" "4C" "TH" "4D" "JS" "4H" "JC" "5S" "JD" "5C" "JH" "5D" "QS" "5H" "QC" "6S" "QD" "6C" "QH" "6D" "KS" "6H" "KC" "7S" "KD" "7C" "KH" "7D" "AS" "7H" "AC" "8S" "AD" "8C" "AH"]
["2S" "5C" "8D" "JH" "2C" "5D" "8H" "QS" "2D" "5H" "9S" "QC" "2H" "6S" "9C" "QD" "3S" "6C" "9D" "QH" "3C" "6D" "9H" "KS" "3D" "6H" "TS" "KC" "3H" "7S" "TC" "KD" "4S" "7C" "TD" "KH" "4C" "7D" "TH" "AS" "4D" "7H" "JS" "AC" "4H" "8S" "JC" "AD" "5S" "8C" "JD" "AH"]
["2S" "TS" "5C" "KC" "8D" "3H" "JH" "7S" "2C" "TC" "5D" "KD" "8H" "4S" "QS" "7C" "2D" "TD" "5H" "KH" "9S" "4C" "QC" "7D" "2H" "TH" "6S" "AS" "9C" "4D" "QD" "7H" "3S" "JS" "6C" "AC" "9D" "4H" "QH" "8S" "3C" "JC" "6D" "AD" "9H" "5S" "KS" "8C" "3D" "JD" "6H" "AH"]
["2S" "6S" "TS" "AS" "5C" "9C" "KC" "4D" "8D" "QD" "3H" "7H" "JH" "3S" "7S" "JS" "2C" "6C" "TC" "AC" "5D" "9D" "KD" "4H" "8H" "QH" "4S" "8S" "QS" "3C" "7C" "JC" "2D" "6D" "TD" "AD" "5H" "9H" "KH" "5S" "9S" "KS" "4C" "8C" "QC" "3D" "7D" "JD" "2H" "6H" "TH" "AH"]
["2S" "4S" "6S" "8S" "TS" "QS" "AS" "3C" "5C" "7C" "9C" "JC" "KC" "2D" "4D" "6D" "8D" "TD" "QD" "AD" "3H" "5H" "7H" "9H" "JH" "KH" "3S" "5S" "7S" "9S" "JS" "KS" "2C" "4C" "6C" "8C" "TC" "QC" "AC" "3D" "5D" "7D" "9D" "JD" "KD" "2H" "4H" "6H" "8H" "TH" "QH" "AH"]
["2S" "3S" "4S" "5S" "6S" "7S" "8S" "9S" "TS" "JS" "QS" "KS" "AS" "2C" "3C" "4C" "5C" "6C" "7C" "8C" "9C" "TC" "JC" "QC" "KC" "AC" "2D" "3D" "4D" "5D" "6D" "7D" "8D" "9D" "TD" "JD" "QD" "KD" "AD" "2H" "3H" "4H" "5H" "6H" "7H" "8H" "9H" "TH" "JH" "QH" "KH" "AH"]
["2S" "2D" "3S" "3D" "4S" "4D" "5S" "5D" "6S" "6D" "7S" "7D" "8S" "8D" "9S" "9D" "TS" "TD" "JS" "JD" "QS" "QD" "KS" "KD" "AS" "AD" "2C" "2H" "3C" "3H" "4C" "4H" "5C" "5H" "6C" "6H" "7C" "7H" "8C" "8H" "9C" "9H" "TC" "TH" "JC" "JH" "QC" "QH" "KC" "KH" "AC" "AH"]
["2S" "2C" "2D" "2H" "3S" "3C" "3D" "3H" "4S" "4C" "4D" "4H" "5S" "5C" "5D" "5H" "6S" "6C" "6D" "6H" "7S" "7C" "7D" "7H" "8S" "8C" "8D" "8H" "9S" "9C" "9D" "9H" "TS" "TC" "TD" "TH" "JS" "JC" "JD" "JH" "QS" "QC" "QD" "QH" "KS" "KC" "KD" "KH" "AS" "AC" "AD" "AH"]
```

### Explanation

```
A,2>s"TJQKA"+"SCDH"m*{_p26/z:~}8*p
A,                                 "Get the range from 0 to 9.";
  2>                               "Slice off first two elements.";
    s                              "Convert to string '23456789'.";
     "TJQKA"+                      "Append this string.";
             "SCDH"                "Push the suits.";
                   m*              "Take the Cartesian product. This yields the first line.";
                     {        }8*  "Execute this block 8 times.";
                      _p           "Duplicate the last line and print it.";
                        26/        "Split the array into halves.";
                           z       "Zip, i.e. transpose the array.";
                            :~     "Flatten the array.";
                                 p "Print the final deck.";
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code? I'm curious.

Comment: @Thrax Done. Totally forgot about that.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Great solution, i love the `A,2>` to get the numbers, good thinking!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 97 bytes

Saved a few bytes with a convenient out-of-order deck

```r
d=paste(rep(c(2:10,"A","J","Q","K"),4),quote(S(C,D,H)))
for(i in 1:9)print(d<-c(t(matrix(d,26))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8W2ILG4JFWjKLVAI1nDyMrQQEfJUUlHyQuIA4HYW0lTx0RTp7A0H6goWMNZx0XHQ1NTkystv0gjUyEzT8HQylKzoCgzr0QjxUY3WaNEIzexpCizQiNFx8gMqFDz/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 753 bytes

```
/*/\/\///}/S,*'/C,*"/D,*;/H,*b/A'*c/A"*d/A;*e/2}*f/2'*g/2"*h/2;*i/3}*j/3'*k/3"*l/3;*m/4}*n/4'*o/4"*p/4;*q/5}*r/5'*s/5"*t/5;*u/6}*v/6'*w/6"*x/6;*y/7}*z/7'*-/7"*B/7;*+/8}*!/8'*E/8"*F/8;*G/9}*@/9'*I/9"*_/9;*(/10}*L/10'*M/10"*N/10;*O/J}*P/J'*)/J"*R/J;*$/Q}*T/Q'*U/Q"*V/Q;*W/K}*X/K'*Y/K"*{/KH
A}/A}bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-B+!EFG@I_(LMNOP)R$TUVWXY{-bBc+d!eEfFgGh@iIj_k(lLmMnNoOpPq)rRs$tTuUvVwWxXyYz{n-NboBOcp+Pdq!)erERfsF$gtGThu@UivIVjw_Wkx(XlyLYmzM{GnT-hNub@oUBiOvcIpV+jPwd_qW!k)xe(rXElRyfLsYFm$zgMt{qGWn!Tk-)hxNeu(br@XoEUlBRiyOfvLcsIYpFVm+$jzPgwMdt_{iqyGOWfnv!LTcks-I)YhpxFNVemu+($bjrz@PXgowEMUdltB_R{eimquy+G(O$Wbfjnrvz!@LPTXcgkosw-EIM)UYdhlptxBF_NRV{cegikmoqsuwy-+EGI(MO)$UWYbdfhjlnprtvxzB!F@_LNPRTVX{bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-B+!EFG@I_(LMNOP)R$TUVWXYKH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldFZbqMIFEDR/9oFCAl4xHpVmSN@MF1AiJlCYQapJNTYmNFgM5lBrD2dLbSudDZw2/LfNo3bry8E/Psd4op/7oDGf@6AxN93wOP7HUS4peGAWxKOuOUhxvsVTnhPQ4L3JKR4z0OGDyvk@EBDgQ8klPjAwxkfV6jwkYYaH0m44CMPV3xaocEnGlp8IqHDJx56fF5hwGcabvhMwojPPEz4ssKMLzRs8IUEEV944PB1BQJfaZDwlQQZX3lQ8G0FAd9oUPGNhBDfeGDw188VtG9p0L8lwfiWBxM/VrDwgwYWP0iw8YMHCj9XcPCThj1@kuDiJw8e7lbwcUdDgDsSFty9/9iuuF2jwzE@JWmWF@W5qi/Xpu364TZO80bkCElWBDVkNN0wLdamnL3r@cGyicQDdyRi6SQnSipkah4WTKmd9cqozYt1ZRu7pTqn3w/uzRv9KZiXamNEtWgeLpx1vBJs3Ej2qZWppFOctBf22aC6@S30ipHxy0kLzrO@KJWzSY0@Euq9mJnDQb24XG7djuHVIwp2jJnGl0p7OmltIJ@pOdG75ap4FeEUGzYdjbhnokbwa2lfinY2madBO7RqcJHdM0fls5Xc9GMXLtl1UkzvVA2E5hyKdqOyQXoZZcONzz3HUFHezILlJ/VN0vfHshNDe4mz87WfOIUxKS865VUzzISgWY5/SIq6vW0kVWf3wTEtL90oyqFhu8shTrLiXF/b/jZtOElRGd1kqb0XRMdTmpfVpemGcRYJWQg1w7Id11/@/5fd@9fXfw)

Uses the example output (it's pretty fit for this purpose) without the trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 31 bytes

```
9o åÈó c}"SCDH"ï"TJQKA"i2ò9 ¬¹w
```

[Try it!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=OW8g5cjzIGN9IlNDREgi7yJUSlFLQSJpMvI5IKy5dw==&input=LVE=)

Although Japt has a reasonable "interleave two lists" function, it does not have a great "separate into halves" option. Instead I opted to *unshuffle* a deck and just display those steps in reverse.

Explanation:

```
9o                           ¹     Generate 9 rows, starting with...
         "SCDH"                      The suits
               ï                     Cartesian product with...
                "TJQKA"                The "special" card values
                       i               Concatenated with...
                        2ò9 ¬          Digits 2-9 as a string; i.e. "23456789"
   å    }                          And getting each subsequent row by "unshuffling":
    Èó                               Separate every-other card; e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6] -> [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
       c                             and flatten the two lists; e.g. [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]] -> [1,3,5,2,4,6]
                              w    Display in reverse order
```

I could [save 2 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=OW8g5cjzIGN9IlNDREgi7yJUSlFLImk59SCsuXc=&input=LVE=) if I could use 1 for aces instead of A, but none of the other answers did that

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2TŸ.•-Ÿ•S«.•ôì•âJ9F=2äζ˜
```

Uses lowercase cards to save 2 bytes with compression, since any human-readable output is allowed.
Starting/ending deck is:

```
['2c','2d','2h','2s','3c','3d','3h','3s','4c','4d','4h','4s','5c','5d','5h','5s','6c','6d','6h','6s','7c','7d','7h','7s','8c','8d','8h','8s','9c','9d','9h','9s','10c','10d','10h','10s','ac','ad','ah','as','jc','jd','jh','js','qc','qd','qh','qs','kc','kd','kh','ks']
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fKOToDr1HDYt0j@4AksGHVoM4h7ccXgOiFnlZutkaHV5ybtvpOf//AwA) (PS: Uses the legacy TIO because it is much faster.. All builtins that were used in this answer are the same in both the Python legacy and Elixir rewrite versions of 05AB1E however.)

**Explanation:**

```python
2TŸ           # List in the range [2,10]: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
   .•-Ÿ•      # Compressed string "ajqk"
        S     # As a list of characters: ["a","j","q","k"]
         «    # Merge the lists together: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"a","j","q","k"] 
.•ôì•         # Compressed string "cdhs"
     â        # Create each possible pair (cartesian product)
      J       # Join each pair together (now we have our deck of cards)
9F            # Loop 9 times:
  =           #  Print the deck with trailing newline, without popping the deck
   2ä         #  Split it in two equal parts
     ζ        #  Zip it (swap rows/columns)
      ˜       #  Flatten the list of lists
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•-Ÿ•` is `"ajqk"` and `.•ôì•` is `"cdhs"`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 69 bytes

```
([o] {.say;.[flat ^26 Z 26..*]}xx 9)(«A {2..10} J Q K»X~ <S C D H>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/18jOj9WoVqvOLHSWi86LSexRCHOyEwhSsHITE9PK7a2okLBUlPj0GpHhWojPT1Dg1oFL4VABe9DuyPqFGyCFZwVXBQ87DT//wcA)

- `{ .say; .[flat ^26 Z 26..*] }` is an anonymous function that prints its argument list, then returns a perfect shuffle of that list
- `xx 9` produces a list containing nine copies of that anonymous function
- `[o]` reduces that list with the function composition operator `o`, producing a function that calls the original anonymous function nine times, passing the shuffled list down each level
- Finally, the original unshuffled deck is passed to that composed function.  `«A {2..10} J Q K»` is a list of the ranks, `<S C D H>` is a list of the suits, and `X~` produces the cross product of those lists with the string concatenation operator `~`.

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z86P1ajWq84sdJaLzrOyEwhSsHITE9Py1ortraiQsFSU@PQakeFaiM9PUODWgUvhUAF70O7I@oUbIIVnBVcFDzsNP//BwA "Perl 6 – Try It Online")